# How to Session an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, types, casting

I store a join from two table in a `var` anonymous type variable:

```
var results = from t in db.Table1
              join j in db.Table2 on t.IDCourse equals j.IDCourse
              select new { t, j };
```

now, what I need to do is to store this kind of object in session. But I need to specify the type of the object.

Doing `results.GetType()` I got:

```
System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Table1,Table2 ]]
```

but I'm not sure how to translate this in a common type. How would you do this kind of "conversion"?

Comment: Either introduce a new type and map to that, or read it as `dynamic`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: using `dynamic` I can't group or made LINQ queries later. Which will be this "new type"? That's the question...

Comment: @markzzz: do you really need both types in an anonymous type? Since both are related/linked you could extend the `Table1` with a property `Table2`. Then you only need to store the `Table1` instance but you can use it's prperty `Table2`(choose better names)..

Comment: Why are you storing two tables into session? Why can't you get the data directly from db?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: of course I can extend Table1, but it must contains some fields of Table 2. How would you do this in LINQ?

Comment: @markzzz: if you extend it with a property of type `Table2` you have all properties of `Table2`. I also don't want you to change the table but the class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: not sure what you are talking about? Have you an example?

Comment: @Kaf: I need to do async filtering of the table (concat result) using a webservices. So, I need to store the "current" result before filtering again using different filters.

Comment: You can face some problems, specially with state server or database storing state, because anonymous types are not marked as serializable.
It will work fine if you create a class that represents the types Table1 and Table2, and use select new NewType { t, j }.

Comment: @RicardoPontual: I'm in ReadOnly mode, so I won't affect any data in the DB.

Comment: I think KeyValuePair<T,J> can help. result will be a enumerable of KVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Linq-To-Sql` classes are generated as partial. This means you can have separate code files with the same class names declared as partial to add the extra properties you want.

```
public partial class Table1
{
     .... auto generated stuff ....
}
```

How you can extend it, create another file like this:

```
public partial class Table1
{
     public Table2 Table2{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create an instance in this way:

```
var results = from t in db.Table1
              join j in db.Table2 on t.IDCourse equals j.IDCourse
              select new { t, j };
foreach(var x in results)
    x.t.Table2 = x.j;
return results.Select(x => x.t).ToList();
```

Now every `Table1` instance in this list contains `Table2` as property.

Comment: Oh no I won't touch the LINQ-To-SQL classes. I've had many problems in the past when I delete table and I re-import them, due to edits on DB.

Comment: @markzzz: then go with a completely new class. But by using a separate code file the auto-generated stuff doesn't conflict with the other partial class.

Comment: Not sure if I'm see it correct, but why using join in LINQ it makes "two" table/class? Join means "join", so a single object should be used :O

Comment: @markzzz: if this is Linq-To-SQL and you have defined foreign-keys why is the property not already available?

Comment: @markzzz I think you may need to read up on `Linq` and joins etc

Comment: Because the property is in Table2, not in Table1. Yes I've foreign-keys, but when I do a query, after a group by, I can't do g.Table2.field. Or at least, i can't see there...

Comment: @markzzz: then show that query, maybe we can help. Of course the group has no such property, but every item in the group has it.

Comment: Ok I've got what you mean. Yes, I don't really any join here! In fact I can just use Table1. The problem remains: I can't store in session Linq-To-SQL object (they are not serializable), so I always need a wrapper to store  successive filter/query table result.

Comment: @markzzz: it doesn't need to be serializable to be stored in `Session` since the session is just server memory. Maybe you mean `ViewState` which i wouldn't use for database stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example class storing both of the objects you require:

```
public class TableStorage
{
    public Table1 Table1 {get;set;}
    public Table2 Table2 {get;set;}
}
...
var results = (from t in db.Table1
              join j in db.Table2 on t.IDCourse equals j.IDCourse
              select new TableStorage { Table1 = t, Table2 = j }).ToList();
```

Now store the `results` in your session:

`Session["TableData"] = results;`

Then, you can get the data back:

`List<TableStorage> data = (List<TableStorage>)Session["TableData"];`

This may or may not be what you require, so feel free to comment.

Comment: But the tables (after the join) become an unique table. Why in your example there is a List of table?

Comment: unique table? I'm not sure I follow. in your example, you create an anonymous type, which as you've discovered is not always the best approach. Here, `TableStorage` is essentially a wrapper to store references of the data brought back from your db and can be stored / retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create viewmodel (if it's for web view) :

```
class YourViewModel()
{
    public object Table1 {get; set;}
    public object Table2 {get; set;}

    YourViewModel(dynamic LINQResult)
    {
        this.Table1 = LINQResult.prop1;
        this.Table2 = LINQResult.prop2;
    }
}
```

Change object to your type and names of props etc to your names.